# Display Recyclerview inside alertDialog

Tags: java, android

```
imgTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder  =   new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                                    mBuilder.setTitle("Location Available!");
                                    LayoutInflater inflater =   getLayoutInflater();
                                    View convertView        =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.reclycer_data, null);

                                    RecyclerView list       =   convertView.findViewById(R.id.recView);
                                    list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
                                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                                    AlertDialog dialog      =   mBuilder.create();
                                    dialog.show();
                                }
                            });
```

I want to show my Recyclerview in AlertDialog like the code, I'm pretty sure i already follow in the videos but its always force close when i open my alertDialog. Can you guys help me? i'm new use android studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use custom layout dialog to add your custom layout to dialog. Try using below given code. 
Hope this will be a helpful answer.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext(), R.style.FullHeightDialog);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.reclycer_data);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    if (dialog.getWindow() != null){
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    RecyclerView list = dialog.findViewById(R.id.recView);
    list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

dialog.show();
```

- Define dialog style in style.xml

  ```
  <style name="FullHeightDialog" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
      <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
      <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
      <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
  </style>
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Dialog context must Activity

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YouActivity.this);
    mBuilder.setTitle("Location Available!");
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reclycer_data, null);

    RecyclerView list = convertView.findViewById(R.id.recView);
    list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    mBuilder.setView(convertView); // setView

    AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();
```